# Keyboard is blocking my edit text

Tags: android-studio, layout, android-edittext

I don't know why the keyboard is blocking the space where I can type. My guess is that it is a layout issue, since it kind of works when I have an action bar enabled, but I don't want the action bar. And yes I've tried going into manifest and put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"(also resize, stateAlwaysHidden). I looked at most of the forums relating to this problem. Also, to mention that the username is located in the bottom half of the app.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_button"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
    android:textColorHint="@color/buttonTextColor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/createAccount"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_button"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
    android:textColorHint="@color/buttonTextColor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/terms"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="@string/goBack"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appTitle"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.65"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/appColor"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/slogan"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/slogan"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="@string/slogan"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="374dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/terms"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/terms"
    android:textColor="@color/buttonTextColor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createAccount" />


 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this attribute in your activity

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
/>
```

If it doesn't work put this in `onCreate()` method after setContentView:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```